# Can't run a linux shell function from NPM script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, npm, package.json

I Just defined a function in my .bashrc (and then in my .bash_profile) file. Now I'm trying to run this function, that works fine in terminal, from my package.json with `npm`

So I get this in my .bashrc file:

```
function emu(){
    ~/android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -use-system-libs -avd "$1"
}
```

and I defined this script in my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "emulator": "emu ReactNative",
    ...
  },
```

And I get this error in console:

```
> emu ReactNative

sh: 1: emu: not found
```

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: You'll have to do something like: `"emulator": "bash  -ic 'emu ReactNative'"` -- the -i will tell bash you want an interactive shell, so read your ~/.bashrc file

Comment: @glennjackman worked!